# EXT JS - all-classes.js is throwing error-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: jsp, extjs4.1, uncaught-exception

I am building the all-classes.js using the following command

```
sencha compile -classpath=ext/src,app page -in index.jsp -o build/index.jsp.
```

After that I am getting the all-classes.js file.

But while running the application with all-classes.js included, it is throwing an `JS error` as below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way we can know what is causing an error, there could be a miriad of things wrong. It could be a missing class, it could be a wrong order of inclusion, it could be a syntax error...

You need to step back and assemble your app piece by piece until you know what specific file is causing the issue.